# RAM burst, myth or reality?

Tags: virtualization, vps, memory, openvz

Often when buying a VPS, we are faced with a number of features. These include the RAM.
In XEN virtualization RAM and swap is (or should be) dedicated.
In OpenVZ, how important is "burst"?
I ask because I have some doubts about the real importance of this value.
Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

"Burst" is the hard upper limit of allocatable memory.  "guarenteed" is a soft, exceedable limit.

More info can be found [here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=6933231&postcount=16) and [here](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/why-i-dont-like-openvz-vps-plans-with-large-burstable-memory/)